# How to make load testing for web application that based on Webrtc

Tags: web, jmeter, webrtc, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

Im trying to make load testing for web application that based on Webrtc,
does someone knows with whitch tool can I test that application.
also I`d like to know if i can use Jmeter and if so , how can i use it ?
thanks a head

Comment: Had a look at this already ? https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/ESUdvte1uAo

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to load testing, WebRTC is different. And that's because WebRTC is peer-to-peer and not client server.

What you can test is the client server part, more specifically the signaling server and the STUN/TURN server. For these, you can easily use JMeter as for any web server. For STUN/TURN just follow the specs (though if you're using an existing server, I would leave this into the authors hands, unless you want to involve in that project too). For the signaling server, it depends on how you build it.

What you can also do with WebRTC is try to test with a controlled limited bandwidth and delay/jitter. This will be more like a smoke test, than a load one. To do this automatically is a little bit more complicated. especially if you want to do it with audio/video, not data.

Comment: thanks for your quick response, as you probably know it is possible to use MCU server in order to create one2many communication.  i want to simulate that flow, the problem here in my opinion is that the sdp and the trickle ICE negotitation runs under secure protocols, and i dont know if there is a possibility to simulate it using Jmeter.  i forgot to mention that the clients and the MCU server running under the same LAN, and thats why i dont need  STUN or TURN server.

Comment: You can check with loadmultiplier.com , looks they have support for webrtc. Disclaimer: I work for loadmultiplier team.